Why doesn't TanStack/React Query seem to be retrieving data from the cache if the queryKey matches?
I'm relatively new to TanStack/React Query. I'm currently trying to utilize it's caching mechanism in my app. From my understanding, when using useQuery, if you provide a queryKey, data will be stored in React Query's cache. Any subsequent uses of useQuery with a matching queryKey means that data will be fetched from the cache instead of a new network request, provided the data is not stale. For the purposes of testing, I've tried to set staleTime and gcTime to longer than default amounts.
In my app, I have a layout.tsx at /loans/[id] where I am fetching a loan object.
//layout.tsx
 const {
    isFetched,
    error,
    isFetching,
    isStale,
    data: loan,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["loan", params.id],
    queryFn: () => fetch(`/api/loans/${params.id}`).then((res) => res.json()),
    staleTime: 300000,
    gcTime: 300000
  });

if (isInitialLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const queryCache = queryClient.getQueryData(["loan", params.id])
  console.log("This is in the query cache:" + queryCache)

queryCache is always initially undefined and (although isInitialLoading is depreciated) <div>Loading...</div> always displays at visiting any route past /loans/[id]/.... Additionally, isStale is always initially true. Which leads me to believe the cache isn't being utilized, though I'd like it to be!
I'm fetching that data again on a component at /loans/[id]/activity-log, because I need to pass down the loan object as props to another component at that route.
//ActivityLog.tsx
const {
    isFetching,
    error,
    data: loan,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["loan", params.id],
    queryFn: () => fetch(`/api/loans/${params.id}`).then((res) => res.json()),
  });

  if (isFetching) {
    console.log("fetching from activity log page")
  }

Curiously, the console.log("fetching from activity log page") never shows in my console at that route which seems to suggest that the cache IS being utilized here, since presumably the loan object is available from layout.tsx's query..
My guess is that it's by some virtue of using useQuery on a layout.tsx, and the Next.js App router that React Query is not reading the cache on each render of any component that's using the layout.tsx? Or maybe I am misunderstanding staleTime/gcTime or this is more in the realm of data persistence instead of caching?

Are you using v5? If so you should be using isLoading instead of isInitialLoading. Quick reference:
v5 isPending === v4 isLoading
v5 isLoading === v4 isInitialLoading
